# Flickering Brightness Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, flicker

I am having an issue with the brightness flickering on my machine that is running Ubuntu 20.04. My machine is dual booted, and this only happens when I am using Ubuntu.

I have seen a lot of other posts out there talking about a similar issue, but none of the resolutions have worked for me. I have recorded a video (see link below) of the flickering to hopefully help narrow down an answer.

https://giphy.com/gifs/YT8GA1ExAPqAa0POiv

Has anyone seen this issue before? I am currently dual booted on a Lenovo Yoga 730-15ikb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case the solution was disabling "Automatic Brightness" in the Power options of the settings menu.

Comment: This solved the issue for me.

Comment: It shouldn't have taken me so much googling but this fixed my issue on my X1 carbon running elementary os. This issue has been driving me nuts for ages.